# Pandas DataFrame Cannot Read Data

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe

I'm having an issue with pandas that I didn't have a few months ago. I am trying to take a set of data from user input (using tkinter) and putting it into a pandas dataframe. Here is what the data looks like:

```
1.000000    03/27/2016   13:29:26.098   1431.778943 0.092089
1.000000    03/27/2016   13:29:26.298   1432.410517 0.078570
1.000000    03/27/2016   13:29:26.498   1431.905258 0.089538
1.000000    03/27/2016   13:29:26.698   1431.399999 0.080930
5.000000    03/28/2016   00:00:00.098   1289.422164 0.392945
25.000000   03/28/2016   00:00:00.298   1289.295849 0.145016
25.000000   03/28/2016   00:00:00.498   1289.295849 0.183149
25.000000   03/28/2016   00:00:00.698   1288.790590 0.175114
26.000000   03/28/2016   00:25:16.698   1302.053644 0.162170
.....
```

The 5 columns are set, but there are usually somewhere between 200,000 to 800,000 lines in a dataset.

Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename() #User selects file

file = pd.read_table(file_path, index_col=False)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=file, columns=['Measurement', 'Date', 'Time','CO2', 'Flow'], dtype=object)

print(file_path)
print(file)
print(df)
```

print(file_path) outputs the correct path, print(file) shows all of the correct data, and print(df) shows this:

```
 Measurement Date Time  CO2 Flow
0            NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1            NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2            NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3            NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
4            NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
5            NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
6            NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
7            NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
8            NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
.......
```

I had done the exact same thing before, but I lost the script I was working on and needed to start over. It worked perfectly before, but I'm not sure what happened. I have tried several things to fix it:

1. Changing pd.read_table to pd.io.parsers.read_table
2. Changed index=, dtype=, and other properties of pd.DataFrame
3. Converted the file to a .csv and used pd.read_csv
4. Shortened the file significantly
5. Creating a pd.Series with a single column and printing that but still had NaN for all data points

I can easily generate a random set of data and make it into a pd.DataFrame with no problem (I used df2 = DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 5)columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']) in ipython and it displayed correctly).

I made a numpy array with the same data and it worked fine. I want to use pandas because I think it will be easier for my analysis in the long run. I really hope it is something small that I'm missing, but I've been working on this for a while so I'm willing to try anything.

Comment: I think you can omit `df = pd.DataFrame(data=file, columns=['Measurement', 'Date', 'Time','CO2', 'Flow'], dtype=object)`, because `file` is `DataFrame`.

Comment: You're effectively reindexing your old df when you pass it as the data param to the DataFrame constructor, if you passed a np array then it would work: `pd.DataFrame(data=file.values, columns=['Measurement', 'Date', 'Time','CO2', 'Flow'], dtype=object)` Also if your file had no column names you can usually either pass the desired names as a param to `read_table` but usually you have to tell it that there is no header `header=None`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the documentation of [read_table](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_table.html), you are already getting the DataFrame in file.

Try this:

```
In [71]: f = pd.read_table('table.txt', names=['Measurement', 'Date', 'Time','CO2', 'Flow'])

In [72]: f
Out[72]:
   Measurement        Date          Time          CO2      Flow
0            1  03/27/2016  13:29:26.098  1431.778943  0.092089
1            1  03/27/2016  13:29:26.298  1432.410517  0.078570
2            1  03/27/2016  13:29:26.498  1431.905258  0.089538
3            1  03/27/2016  13:29:26.698  1431.399999  0.080930
4            5  03/28/2016  00:00:00.098  1289.422164  0.392945
5           25  03/28/2016  00:00:00.298  1289.295849  0.145016
6           25  03/28/2016  00:00:00.498  1289.295849  0.183149
7           25  03/28/2016  00:00:00.698  1288.790590  0.175114
8           26  03/28/2016  00:25:16.698  1302.053644  0.162170
```

So why you were not getting the desired result?
Observe that after the table has been read, it doesnt have desired column names.

```
In [77]: file = pd.read_table('table.txt', index_col=False)

In [78]: file
Out[78]:
   1.000000  03/27/2016  13:29:26.098  1431.778943  0.092089
0         1  03/27/2016  13:29:26.298  1432.410517  0.078570
1         1  03/27/2016  13:29:26.498  1431.905258  0.089538
2         1  03/27/2016  13:29:26.698  1431.399999  0.080930
3         5  03/28/2016  00:00:00.098  1289.422164  0.392945
4        25  03/28/2016  00:00:00.298  1289.295849  0.145016
5        25  03/28/2016  00:00:00.498  1289.295849  0.183149
6        25  03/28/2016  00:00:00.698  1288.790590  0.175114
7        26  03/28/2016  00:25:16.698  1302.053644  0.162170
```

Hence when you call DataFrame constructor with an existing DataFrame and with Column names, you get all null values because, there is no column by the names give in the input DataFrame.

```
In [80]: df = pd.DataFrame(data=file, columns=['Measurement', 'Date', 'Time','CO2', 'Flow'], dtype=object)

In [81]: df
Out[81]:
  Measurement Date Time  CO2 Flow
0         NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1         NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2         NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3         NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
4         NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
5         NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
6         NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
7         NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Your posts have significantly contributed me in learning pandas! I appreciate you!

Comment: Thank you! I read the documentation, but I read past the "Read general delimited file **_into_** DataFrame". I thought I still needed to put the read file into a dataframe. That was a great way of explaining it too, thanks!